# Firebug: Inspect POST from webpage

Tags: firefox, firebug, html-post

Can I use Firebug to inspect a post request sent by a webpage to a server and if so how?

I am refering inspecting a regular POST made using a form, but would also be interested in knowing how to inspect posts using javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can do that. The [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) allows you to expand every request related to a website. For a POST done via AJAX you can set the *XHR* filter to see only those requests.

If you expand a request by clicking on it, you'll get all the information related to it.

Sebastian

Comment: Ok, understood, my mistake was that I was on the XHR tab whilst testing for a non JS post: I needed to click on the All or HTML tabs to view it. Thanks